# Two functions in JavaScript onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

```
<a href="#" type="image"  class="topopup"  onclick="ShowDIV3();"  >Click Here</a>
```

In this code I need to execute another one function like validation if that function is true only the next function should run otherwise it won't be run. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
<a href="#" type="image"  class="topopup"  onclick="ShowDIV3();"  >Click Here</a>

function ShowDIV3() {
    if(true)   //Here can use condition for validation
       another_fun();
    else
       return false;
}
```

call your another function when the condition is true at your `showDIV3` function

Comment: seems they just got the 125 rep :P. Move on brother..keep answering .

Answer (score 5):

Try this code :

```
<a href="#" type="image"  class="topopup"  onclick="if (ShowDIV3()) {myotherfunction()}">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: `if(whatever == true)` is exactly equivalent to `if(whatever)`. If you really want to check for `true` and only `true` (i.e., not something which evaluates to `true`, like `1`, `"some text"` etc.), use `if(whatever === true)`.

Comment: This should really be re-factored out the html.

Comment: @LucasWillems Yes, testing for `== true` will work, but is quite pointless, because the `if` statement already evaluates its condition to a boolean value. The `==` operator is quite sloppy (or "helpful" if you will) which can be dangerous in some cases. I.e., `1 == true` will evaluate to `true`, whereas `1 === true` will evaluate to `false`, which is probably what you will want in most comparison cases. Keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your explication.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
onclick=" if (ValidateFunction()) return ShowDIV3();"
```

Answer (score 1):

in jquery you could do it like this, this will also allow multiple handlers and better event normalization and improved separation of concerns.

```
$(".topopup").on("click", function(){
     if (ShowDIV3()){
         OtherStuff();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `showDIV3()` function at the end have something like this,

```
function showDIV3()
{
    // Your process, and then at the end,

    if(result)
    {
        // Call the other function
    }
    else 
    {
       // Return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why `returning` there and executing ?? why not simply ??

```
  function  ShowDIV3(){


      -----

    if(resultBoolean){
     proceedToanotherFunc();

    }

    }
```

*Imho* This would be more readable,other that writing logic there in *html*

Answer (score 0):

Do your validation in `ShowDIV3()` function, and depending on the validation call your next function from inside the `ShowDIV3()` function

Answer (score 0):

Just create more statement in your javascript like

```
function ValidateStatments() {

    var val = document.getElementById("Value 1").value;
    var val2 = document.getElementById("Value 2").value;


    if(val != "Value 1"){
        return false;
     }
    else if (val2 != "Value2){
        return false;
    }
return true;
}
```

and on your link add your javascript so if its true, it will allow the user to do the action `onclick="return ValidateStatments();"`